# How do I auto-resize an image to fit a div container

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

I am trying to create an responsive website. I am trying to add an image to every container with 70% width. But I don't know how to set the image to adjust as the screens size changes. I mean I wanna make the image inside the container be responsive as well.

I am not sure if I am describing my problem clear enough, please let me know if you are confused or have any questions.

Comment: add some working code what error you got. how did you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@troy-wu, what do you think of this?

Try adjusting the viewport width here! https://jsfiddle.net/rickydam/ob4umwp3/

```css
.one {
  width: 70%;
  background-color: lightgray;
  display: inline-block;
}

.two {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: gray;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -5px;
}

img {
  max-height: 20vw;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <img src="https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/modules/logos_page/Octocat.png">
</div>

<div class="two">
  <img src="https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/modules/logos_page/Octocat.png">
</div>
```

Comment: awesome, that's what I am looking for. thanks. BTW, what does "-5px" do?

Comment: ok i got this. so i dont need to find two images with the same height, right? we can edit two different size of images by using css

Comment: Sorry, it's not StackOverflow code snippets causing the gap between divs. It's just HTML in general that does it. You can either use `width: 69%` on the first div and `width: 30%` on the second div or do 70 and 29, anything you want. https://jsfiddle.net/rickydam/ob4umwp3/2/ Or do `margin-left: -5px` which moves the second div to the left by 5px to close the gap. https://jsfiddle.net/rickydam/ob4umwp3/

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You can have images of different height.

Comment: @TroyWu to remove that 5px gap, you should just remove the space  between those 2 elements or put an HTML comment or something there so there is no space between them. `5px` represents a "space" in html, and I don't think all browsers treat a space as 5px. https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/KqWPMo

Comment: @MichaelCoker That is neat! Did not know that! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @RickyDam fo sho!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the parent element(s) doesn't have a fixed size, then add `width: 70%` to the `img`. The relative `70%` width will scale with the parent as long as the parent is fluid with the page, too.

```css
img {
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C22p.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. if there are two columns, one with 70% width and the other one with 30% width. if I want to make sure both of them have the same height no matter how i adjust the web page, both columns always have the same height. do i need to have the two images with the same height?

Comment: @TroyWu, yes keeping same height will work in some cases.